# Combine equivalent of RxSwift's bind(to:)

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift, combine

I'm an experienced RxSwift user, and had a good working MVVM structure in RxSwift. I'm new to Combine, but I can't for the love of God figure out how to do something similar in Combine. The biggest blocker is a `bind(to:)` equivalent in Combine. I don't know how to chain the result of 1 variable to another.

Here is what I would do in RxSwift:

```
protocol UseCase {
  func execute(id: Int) -> Single<CustomClass>
}

class DefaultUseCase: UseCase {
  func execute(id: Int) -> Single<CustomClass> {
    // Do network call and return in Single format
  }
}


class ViewModel {

  struct Input {
    let load = PublishRelay<Void>()
  }

  struct Output {
    let isButtonEnabled: Driver<Bool>
  }

  let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
  let input = Input()
  let output: Output

  init(id: Int, useCase: UseCase = DefaultUseCase()) {
    let isButtonEnabled = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)

    let action = Action<Void, CustomClass> { id in 
      return useCase.execute(id: id)
    }

    self.output = Output(isButtonEnabled: isButtonEnabled.asDriver())

    input
      .load
      .bind(to: useCase.inputs)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    action
      .elements
      .map { // map CustomClass to Bool }
      .bind(to: isButtonEnabled)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
}
```

The action class is from this framework: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/Action

I cannot figure out how to do something similar in Combine, I've already read some tutorials, but it doesn't make sense to me. It looks like you need what feels like a thousand variables to just put through 1 value to your view/viewController with a viewModel.

I a seeking a piece of code that does exactly the same as the piece of RxSwift code above, but in Combine with some explanation.

Comment: `I cannot figure out how to do something similar in Combine` - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Cristik I'm trying to do the following: user opens screen, load variable in input is triggered, execute the network call via the use case, when the result of the network call comes back, give it back to my viewModel, do something with the result, and push this on a relay that goes to a driver that updates the enabled state of a button in the viewController.

Comment: OK, and at which step did you got stuck? Which part of the RxSwift to Combine conversion poses problems?

Comment: @Cristik Mostly the chaining of 1 relay to another relay. The bind(to:) equivalent is what I'm missing. It seems like I need a thousand variables (publishers and subscribers and subjects in between) to do what I'm doing above in RxSwift with 2 variables. I cannot figure out how to chain the result of the useCase to the `isButtonEnabled` variable in `Output`. It doesn't make sense to me at all. Also, do you need to dispose variables like in RxSwift? I would think so, but again, this part is also unclear to me.

Comment: So it seems the biggest blocker is the `bind(to:)` equivalency, recommending to make this more clear in the question, it will increase the chances you'll get a response.

Comment: Thanks @Cristik, didn't know that it wasn't entirely clear. Will edit the question!

Comment: You really shouldn't be chaining relays in the first place. :-(

Comment: @DanielT. Why not? This has been working for me really well, so I'm interested to hear why this shouldn't be done?

Comment: It confuses where events come in at. If you have an Observable chain `a->b->c` there is a clear source to sink relationship. Events flow through the chain from `a` to `c`. However, if each of those elements is a Subject or Relay, then events can be inserted at any point in the chain and is anathema to the essence of the paradigm.

Comment: "Subjects [and Relays] provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use." -- [Intro to Rx](http://introtorx.com)

Comment: "The essence of functional reactive programming is to specify the dynamic behavior of a value completely at the time of declaration." -- [Heinrich Apfelmus](https://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2011/03/28-essence-frp.html) Subjects and Relays defy that. They are a necessary evil for converting non-reactive code and handing feedback loops but shouldn't be the first thing you reach for to solve a problem.

Answer (score 3):

It has come to my attention that I didn't answer the explicit question about what `bind(to:)` would look like in Combine. Here is the implementation:

```
extension Publisher {
    func bind<S>(to value: S) -> Cancellable where S: Subject, S.Output == Output, S.Failure == Never {
        sink { completion in
            if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                assert(false, "Binding error \(error)")
            }
            value.send(completion: .finished)
        } receiveValue: { output in
            value.send(output)
        }
    }
}
```

---

First, let's simplify your view model:

```
class ViewModel {
    
    struct Input {
        let load = PublishRelay<Void>()
    }
    
    struct Output {
        let isButtonEnabled: Driver<Bool>
    }
    
    let input = Input()
    let output: Output
    
    init(id: Int, useCase: UseCase = DefaultUseCase()) {
        let isButtonEnabled = input.load
            .flatMapLatest { [useCase] in
                useCase.execute(id: id)
                    .map { _ in /* map CustomClass to Bool */ true }
                    .catchAndReturn(false)
            }
            .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { _ in fatalError() })

        self.output = Output(isButtonEnabled: isButtonEnabled)
    }
}
```

I'm not a fan of your `Input` struct here but I'm working with it...

Once you do that, it's easy to see how to translate it:

```
class ViewModelʹ {
    struct Input {
        let load = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    }
    struct Output {
        let isButtonEnabled: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>
    }

    let input = Input()
    let output: Output

    init(id: Int, useCase: UseCase) {
        let isButtonEnabled = input.load
            .map { [useCase] in
                useCase.execute(id: id)
                    .map { _ in /* map CustomClass to Bool */ true }
                    .catch { _ in Just(false) }
            }
            .switchToLatest()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        self.output = Output(isButtonEnabled: isButtonEnabled)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**

Here is how you would go about using the use case response for multiple outputs (This compiles in iOS 13):

```
class ViewModelʹ {
    struct Input {
        let load = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    }
    struct Output {
        let isButtonEnabled: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>
        let somethingElse: AnyPublisher<String, Never>
    }

    let input = Input()
    let output: Output

    init(id: Int, useCase: UseCase) {
        let result = input.load
            .map { [useCase] in
                useCase.execute(id: id)
                    .catch { _ in Empty() }
            }
            .switchToLatest()
            .share()

        let isButtonEnabled = result
            .map { _ in /* map CustomClass to Bool */ true }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        let somethingElse = result
            .map { _ in /* map CustomClass to String */ "" }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        self.output = Output(
            isButtonEnabled: isButtonEnabled,
            somethingElse: somethingElse
        )
    }
}
```

Of course, a lot depends on how you want to handle errors. The above swallows them, but you [might want to expose them for yet another output](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-continual-error-handling).

All of this is turning into a general tutorial rather than answering a question though.

Comment: And what if I need to use the result of the useCase execute for multiple @Published? How do I "store" the AnyPublisher<CustomClass, Error> from the useCase so I can map it to the correct values?

Comment: Just `share()` the result. No need to store anything.

Comment: And what if the result of the execute of the use case needs to be mapped differently for other variables? Because I assume that the `share()` goes after `.switchToLatest().eraseToAnypublisher()` and the mapping code to the Bool happens before? What if the mapping is different?

Comment: I also support iOS 13 and when I remove the custom mapping of the execute of the useCase, and just add `.share()` at the end, I get an error that `switchToLatest()` is only available in iOS 14

Comment: Updated my answer to explain the above.

Comment: Interestingly, `.share()` uses a subject under the hood. But it's used in a more constrained/safer way.

Comment: Despite a better way to write the code in the original question, I'm still interested in the equivalent in Combine of RxSwift's `bind(to:)`.

Comment: @TingYiShih The `bind(to:)` operator is just a wrapper for `subscribe`. You can just use Combine's `subscribe`.